# JQuery/JavaScript Drop Down Menu won't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, fiddle

Okay, so I have a website that I'm trying to make and there's a drop down menu that's supposed to work. I even used one of the answers on here already to get the code for this menu, created all of the appropriate classes and everything, but it still refuses to work. And by that, I mean that it literally just sits there statically. It's supposed to drop down from an image.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>NEStalgia::Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets.css">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="images/header.png" alt="NEStalgia" href="index.html" class="header_menu"/>
                <br />
                <ul class="hover">
                    <li class="hoverli">
                        <img src="images/menubricks.png" alt="menu bar" class="menu_class" />
                        <ul class="file_menu">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
                                <ul class="sub">
                                    <li><a href="headware.html">Headwear</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="apparel.html">Apparel</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="accessories.html">Accessories</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="cosplays.html">Cosplays</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="plushies.html">Plushies</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="registration.html">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="tableinfo">
                    <table id="intro"> 
                        <tr>
                            <td>Welcome to NEStalgia.<br />
                            We are a gaming merchandise online store that takes great 
                            pride in our work. We have hundreds of great options between
                            several categories: headwear, apparel, accessories, and so
                            many more!</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="headwear.html"><img src="images/headwear.png" alt="headwear" /></a>
                                <a href="apparel.html"><img src="images/apparel.png" alt="apparel" /></a>
                                <a href="accessories.html"><img src="images/accessories.png" alt="accessories" /></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Don't forget to check out<br />
                            our coupons page! It's filled with TONS of wonderful coupons
                            that you're sure to love, like 50% off your entire purchase! 
                            Check in every Friday to see the coupons page updated, and be wary: 
                            some coupons start on a specific day, so until that day, you aren't
                            able to use them!</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="cosplays.html"><img src="images/cosplays.png" alt="cosplays" /></a>
                                <a href="plushies.html"><img src="images/plushies.png" alt="plushies" /></td></a>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <footer>
                    <table id="tablefoot">
                        <tr>
                            <td>&copy; Copyright NEStalgia 2015<br />
                            All rights reserved. </td>
                            <td>Disclaimer: The images used on this site<br />
                            have been taken from Google Images. Do not search<br />
                            for this site on Facebook as it is a mock storefront<br />
                            for a final project. Do not attempt to purchase anything<br />
                            from this site either. Thank you for your understanding<br />
                            and cooperation.</td>
                            <td>Interested in keeping up with us?<br />
                            Be sure to check out our Facebook page!</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    height: 100%
}
body {
    background: url('images/mariostar.png') top left repeat-y,
                url('images/mariostar.png') top right repeat-y;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 2000px;
}
a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
footer {
    padding-top: 55px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
img {
    z-index: 1;
}
li { 
    list-style: none;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 920px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
.container #product {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    width: 670px;
}
.container #sidebar {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    float: right;
    width: 224px;
}
.file_menu {
    display:none;
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
    position: relative;
}

.file_menu li {
    background-color: #302f2f;
    position: relative;
}

.file_menu li a {
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding:10px; 
    display:block;
}

.file_menu li a:hover {
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #F00880;
}
.menu_class {
    border:1px solid #1c1c1c;
}
.sub {
    position: absolute;
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
    display: none;
    left: 302px;
    top: 0px;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}
#footer {
    border-left: 10px solid #5AB3FF;
    border-right: 9px solid #5AB3FF;
    background: #A0D3FF;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    width: 98.65%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
#header img {
    margin-left: 3px;
}
#header ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
}
#header ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#intro {
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 1100px;
}
#intro img {
    margin: 5px;
}
#intro tr td:first-of-type {
    width: 250px;
}
#intro tr td:last-of-type {
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
}
#intro td:first-of-type:first-line {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #5AB3FF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#tablefoot {
    padding-left: 100px;
    width: 1300px;
}
#tablefoot tr td {
    font-size: 10px;
}
#tableinfo {
    margin-left: 125px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

**JavaScript & JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hoverli").hover(
  function () {
     $('ul.file_menu').slideDown('medium');
  }, 
  function () {
     $('ul.file_menu').slideUp('medium');
  }
);

     $(".file_menu li").hover(
  function () {
     $(this).children("ul").slideDown('medium');
  },
  function () {
    $(this).children("ul").slideUp('medium');
  }
);
});
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/yutikohercell/68u51juh/light/

**Live Preview**
http://jsfiddle.net/yutikohercell/68u51juh/embedded/result/

Comment: You are missing the jquery reference in the fiddle. Works fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/68u51juh/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add jQuery, otherwise this will not work.

Comment: No problems, this happen sometimes also to me. :)

Comment: @Franco what happens to the menu in a normal browser page if you don't stop the event propagation?

Comment: @gaemaf  You are completely right, I was a little bit rushing because I was also helping someone else. I will Update the fiddle and notice this to the OP. Thank you for point me to this :)

Comment: @HercellYutiko, I have re-updated the fiddle, due to the advice I have got from gaemaf. https://jsfiddle.net/upjkm2b3/8/. It's for you just the same, but has an additional event in side (event.stopPropagation()) which prevents any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use preventdefault and stopimmediatepropagation:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".hoverli").hover(
    function() {
      $('ul.file_menu').slideDown('medium');
    },
    function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('ul.file_menu').slideUp('medium');
    }
  );

  $(".file_menu li").hover(
    function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      $(this).children("ul").slideDown('medium');
    },
    function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      $(this).children("ul").slideUp('medium');
    }
  );
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  height: 100%
}

body {
  background: url('images/mariostar.png') top left repeat-y, url('images/mariostar.png') top right repeat-y;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 2000px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer {
  padding-top: 55px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

img {
  z-index: 1;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 920px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.container #product {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 670px;
}

.container #sidebar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: right;
  width: 224px;
}

.file_menu {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
  position: relative;
}

.file_menu li {
  background-color: #302f2f;
  position: relative;
}

.file_menu li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.file_menu li a:hover {
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F00880;
}

.menu_class {
  border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
}

.sub {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
  display: none;
  left: 302px;
  top: 0px;
}

#content {
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

#footer {
  border-left: 10px solid #5AB3FF;
  border-right: 9px solid #5AB3FF;
  background: #A0D3FF;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 98.65%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#header img {
  margin-left: 3px;
}

#header ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

#header ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#intro {
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 1100px;
}

#intro img {
  margin: 5px;
}

#intro tr td:first-of-type {
  width: 250px;
}

#intro tr td:last-of-type {
  width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
}

#intro td:first-of-type:first-line {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #5AB3FF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#tablefoot {
  padding-left: 100px;
  width: 1300px;
}

#tablefoot tr td {
  font-size: 10px;
}

#tableinfo {
  margin-left: 125px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <ul class="hover">
            <li class="hoverli">
                <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/2dafuyc.jpg" alt="menu bar" class="menu_class" />
                <ul class="file_menu">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li><a href="headware.html">Headwear</a></li>
                            <li><a href="apparel.html">Apparel</a></li>
                            <li><a href="accessories.html">Accessories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="cosplays.html">Cosplays</a></li>
                            <li><a href="plushies.html">Plushies</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="registration.html">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not deface your answers.